# How are body weight measurements taken for competitive purposes regulated/normalised?

Tags: bodyweight, sports, body-measurements

I suppose in some contexts it may be beneficial to fall into a lighter bracket so one is sparring with lighter contenders. Then in other contexts it must be more beneficial to weigh in more heavily, but I can’t think of any examples of such contexts.

In any case, does anything stop contestants in a competition from drinking lots of water and eating lots of food right before their weight measurement is officially taken?

Or conversely from taking tons of (otherwise legal/permitted) diuretics/laxatives and having a big long sweat in the sauna right before if that would so advantage them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physical fitness, but is about the rules of some sport that the question does not specify.

Comment: "in other contexts it must be more beneficial to weigh in more heavily, but I can’t think of any examples" The reason why you can't think of any is probably that none exist.

Comment: Well don’t boxers for example like to keep their weight down because they consider extra weight a disadvantage?

Comment: A boxer does not gain any advantage from temporarily increasing their weight by drinking a lot of water immediately before a weigh in.